# Typescript error: The object can be undefined

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am using vuejs.

```
this.$slots.eventsContent?.[0]?.data = {};
```

I got error from IDE.

```
TS2779: The left-hand side of an assignment expression may not be an optional property access.
```

Do you know how to get rid of error?

Comment: _Don't_ have optional property access on the left-hand side of an assignment statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use optional property.

```
this.$slots.eventsContent[0].data = {};
```

If you get "property maybe undefined error" you can do like this:

```
if (this.$slots.eventsContent && $slots.eventsContent.length > 0) {
    this.$slots.eventsContent[0].data = {}; 
}
```

Just check if the property is not undefined before doing anything. This way typescript will be sure that your variable is defined.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign to a property of something that is possibly undefined. If you are sure that these are not undefined, you can use `this.$slots.eventsContent!.[0]!.data = {}` to ignore it, or if you only want to assign it only if the values are defined then you need nested ifs to check undefined